# Deep learning and Confusion Matrix

Tags: confusion-matrix, conv-neural-network

I trained my model in keras for binary classification. I used Resnet preformer on ImageNet and I got 95% of accuracy. In my dataset, I have 9004 images for training divided into the two class and 2250 images for test divided into the two class. But the  confusion matrix give me

- 4502 0
- 4502 0

can some one help me to know what is the meaning of this resul?

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation for your result is the following (please note that for simplicity the indices start from 1 and not 0):

For calculating the number of correct predictions on your test dataset, one needs to sum the main diagonal of the matrix.

For the first class (class 1), all your predictions are correct.

This can be inferred from your confusion matrix, as the element on the position [1,1] (first_row,first_col) is 4502. Since you have 0 the element on the position [1,2], it means that all the predictions for class 1 are correct.

However, for the second class, which has on the position [2,2] the value 0, this means that none of your predictions for this class are correct.

Practically, we can easily verify that 4502 is on the position [2,1].

Notes:

1. You may have calculated the accuracy/confusion matrix on the wrong dataset. According to your description, 4502 * 2 = 9004, which means that the confusion matrix that you are giving here is for the training set not for the test set.
2. Whenever you see a number on the confusion matrix that does not belong to the main diagonal, that means that you have a case of FP(false positive) or FN(false negative).

Comment: Thanks to you. Yes, I built the confusion gap in the training set. But I got the same result on the test data. I also understood from the confusion matrix that the network doesn't make good predictions on class 2. Yet when I present him with data that didn't start the training, he makes correct predictions for both classes. This may be due to what please. I'm new to deep learning.